# Applying a function for only some indices

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a function `computeLeft` which receives an index and returns four numbers. Something like this:

```
def computeLeft(i):
    return np.array([i*2, i*3, i*4, i*5])
    # edited to correct it
```

Right now in my code I use it like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

results=["val1","val2","val3","val4"]
df[results] = np.vectorize(computeLeft, signature="()->(4)")(range(len(df)))
```

where `df` is some dataframe.

This obviously applies the function to all rows of `df`.
I want to apply this function to *only some* indexes of `df`.

So for example I have a list `[2, 5, 7, 8, 10]`.
I want to compute `computeLeft` only for the indices in the list and that the columns in result have values only for those rows (the rest having Nan).

How can I apply `computeLeft` selectively like this?

Comment: Can you provide a complete [mre] (input data, expected output)? Also, I get an error trying to reproduce your `vectorize` call.

Comment: Why are you even using `np.vectorize` for this function? Does your actual function need that? Assuming your `computeLeft` function is representative, you could just set `i = np.asarray(i)` inside and return `np.array([2*i, 3*i, 4*i, 5*i]).T` and get the exact same result but in a fraction of the time.

Comment: @jared I am interested. Could you elaborate please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to fix your function and its vectorization:

```py
def computeLeft(i):
    return np.array([i*2, i*3, i*4, i*5])

computeLeftVectorized = np.vectorize(computeLeft, signature="()->(n)")
```

However, as mentioned by @jared in his anwser, it is much faster to just write the function as a pure numpy function in the first case.

And to achieve your goal you can use `loc[]`:

```
results=["val1","val2","val3","val4"]

# Add new columns and fill the columns with NaN
df[results] = np.nan

indices_to_change = [2,5,7,8,10]
# change all rows in results with the provided indices
df.loc[indices_to_change, results] = computeLeftVectorized(indices_to_change)
```

This assumes that your dataframe has index labels that are the given integers (the given indices are not just the row number with different index labels).

Answer (score 1):

If `computeLeft` is representative of your actual function then you're better off just writing it in a vectorized way since `np.vectorize` is slow (it's mainly a convenience function and doesn't provide a speed improvement). In this case, you could write your function as:

```py
def computeLeftNumpy(i):
    i = np.asarray(i)
    return np.array([i*2, i*3, i*4, i*5]).T
```

Usage:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

indices_to_change = [2,5,7,8,10]

df = pd.DataFrame({"val1":np.zeros(15),
                   "val2":np.zeros(15),
                   "val3":np.zeros(15),
                   "val4":np.zeros(15)})
print(df)
df.loc[indices_to_change] = computeLeftNumpy(indices_to_change)
print(df)
```

Output:

```py
    val1  val2  val3  val4
0    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
1    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
2    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
3    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
4    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
5    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
6    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
7    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
8    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
9    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
10   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
11   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
12   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
13   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
14   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0

    val1  val2  val3  val4
0    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
1    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
2    4.0   6.0   8.0  10.0
3    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
4    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
5   10.0  15.0  20.0  25.0
6    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
7   14.0  21.0  28.0  35.0
8   16.0  24.0  32.0  40.0
9    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
10  20.0  30.0  40.0  50.0
11   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
12   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
13   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
14   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
```

Speed comparison:

```py
indices_to_change = np.arange(5000)
%timeit computeLeftVectorized(indices_to_change)
7.77 ms ± 30.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit computeLeftNumpy(indices_to_change)
11.6 µs ± 281 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

Clearly the version that doesn't use `np.vectorize` is much faster.

Comment: Thanks! I will read and understand your answer and apply it in the next iteration since we are looking to improve performance

Comment: Good advice on speeding up that function! Please note that your use of `loc[]` only works if the dataframe has exactly 4 rows. Generelly one has to provide the columns names of val1-val4 to `loc[]` for this application.

Comment: @OskarHofmann I assume you meant to say 4 columns. And yes, the number of columns of `.loc[]` must match the number of columns on the right hand side.

Comment: Yes, I meant columns. My bad.